# Third homology group over and abelian group

Tags: homology-cohomology, abelian-groups, exterior-algebra, group-cohomology

I have this question about the third homology group $H_{3}(G,\mathbb{Z}
)$ when $G$ is an abelian group.

I know that there is an injective map of algebras (Kenneth Brown)

$\phi:\bigwedge^{3}(G)\rightarrow H_{3}(G,\mathbb{Z}
)$

given by $u\wedge v\wedge w\mapsto [u|v|w]-[u|w|v]+[w|u|v]-[w|v|u]+[v|w|u]-[v|u|w]$

where $[u|v|w]$ is a $3-$cocycle.

My question is:  **Is  there any way to write $H_{3}(G,\mathbb{Z}
)$  in term of the algebra $\bigwedge^{3}(G)$?**

I was thinking about using the isomorphism of the universal coefficient theorem:

$H_{n}(G,M
)\cong (H_{n}(G,\mathbb{Z}
)\otimes M)\oplus Tor((H_{n-1}(G,\mathbb{Z}
),M)$

When $M=\mathbb{Z}$ and $n=3$, I do not get anything since the tor part is zero.

Thank you!

-------Update------

I found in this paper

"K3 of a field and the Bloch group"
Andrei Suslin

The next lemma. For any abelian group $A$, we have the exact sequence

$0\rightarrow\wedge^{3}(A)\rightarrow H_{3}(A,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow Tor_{1}^{\mathbb{Z}}(A,A)^{-\sigma}\rightarrow 0$

where $\sigma$ is the involution induced by transposition of arguments, the first homomorphism is induced by the homology multiplication and the second is obtained from the composition

$H_{3}(A,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow^{\Delta_{A}}H_{3}(A\times A,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow Tor_{1}^{\mathbb{Z}}(A,A), $

$\Delta_{A}$ being the diagonal map $A\rightarrow A\times A$, $a\mapsto (a,a)$.